# Can a named pipe with a low integrity label have its SACL/DACL modified by a low integrity process?

Tags: windows, permissions, sandbox, windows-permissions

If a named pipe on Windows has a Low Mandatory Level label and `SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_WRITE_UP` in its SACL, but the DACL has `WRITE_DAC` and `WRITE_OWNER` for the current user, can a low integrity process running under that user account modify the SACL/DACL?

The context here is running a separate low-integrity process for sandboxing purposes, using IPC over named pipes to expose certain restricted functionality.

Here's the `accesschk -lv` output for the pipe in question:

```
\\.\Pipe\testpipe123
  DESCRIPTOR FLAGS:
      [SE_DACL_PRESENT]
      [SE_SACL_PRESENT]
  OWNER: wvm\Polynomial
  LABEL: Low Mandatory Level
        SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_WRITE_UP
  [0] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: wvm\Polynomial
        FILE_ADD_FILE
        FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE
        FILE_APPEND_DATA
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
        FILE_READ_DATA
        FILE_READ_EA
        FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
        FILE_WRITE_DATA
        FILE_WRITE_EA
        DELETE
        SYNCHRONIZE
        READ_CONTROL
        WRITE_DAC
        WRITE_OWNER
  SACL:
  [0] : Mandatory Label\Low Mandatory Level
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY
        FILE_READ_DATA
```

My expectation is that no, the SACL and DACL can't be modified, because low integrity processes would receive only the permissions from the low mandatory label at the bottom (list directory + read data) and none of the DACL permissions for the current user, thus not receiving the `WRITE_DAC` or `WRITE_OWNER` permissions.

Am I right? Are there any other factors involved, or things I should consider for ensuring that the low integrity process can't manipulate the pipe unexpectedly?